# PHP Equality Tests/Edge Cases

Tags: php

PHP's non-strict comparison operators (like `==`) have some infamous edge cases that seem super weird, until you realize that PHP will often cast/coerce string variables into different types to do the "right" thing.  This leads to weird behaviors like this

```
//In PHP 5, this returns true
//In PHP 7, this return false
if("1e1"=="0xa")
{
    var_dump("Equal");
}
else
{ 
    var_dump("Not Equal");
}
```

Is there a collected list of all these "strange" edge cases?  Ideally already collected into an automated test suite?

Comment: It doesn't do it any more since PHP 7 (at least for this example).

Comment: Thank you @axiac!  Updated the question to make this clear.